# Drupal 7 book navigation block not rendering sub menu items

Tags: drupal

I created a book and added chapters and sub-chapters to each of those; however, when I add the book navigation block to the primary navigation and it renders on screen, I am not seeing the sub-chapters, only the top level chapters. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score -1):

Did you check **Show as expanded** on menu links that have children?